# Jupyterhub | Cull | SingleUser | Heml

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kubernetes-helm, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, jupyter-irkernel

I have implemented Jupyterhub using Helm chart. I want to remove the user if the user is inactive for specific time. I have implemented that with cull but the problem is that it removes admin user as well. I just want to remove other user apart from admin. [Here is the cull instrucitons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJWyP.png)

Comment: [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Instead, paste it as a [formatted](/help/formatting) code block. Thanks!

Comment: Please copy your code instead of uploading it's image.